# What script should I use to get around the restriction of ImportData in Google spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have column A with URL pages of some internet sites. In column B i use the following function:

"=CONCATENATE(ImportData(URL from column A)".

... to extract the data page as text in this column, but Google Docs has a limitation for this function in 50 functions in the document.

In other words, how each change of URL address in column A, the data of webpage to be extracted in column B in the form of text, like I use the ImportData?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an onOpen trigger that uses [UrlFetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_urlfetchapp#fetch) for each of the urls in column A and sets the text in column B. This would update the spreadsheet every time it was open.

This will probably work (I've never used UrlFetch before):

```
 function onOpen(e){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  //Load all the URLs
  var urls = sheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();

  //Initialize array for content
  var text = [];

  //Loop through URLs
  for(var i = 0; i < urls.length; i += 1){
    if(urls[i][0] === "") continue;//Skip blank cells
    //Fetch the webpage, push the content to the array (inside an array since it needs to be 2d)
    text.push(
      [UrlFetchApp.fetch(urls[i][0]).getContentText()]
    );
  }
  //Store text in spreadsheet in range the size of the text array
  sheet.getRange("B1:B" + text.length).setValues(text);
}
```

If you want to load new content when the url changes, use the onEdit trigger

```
function onEdit(e){
  //Get the active cell
  //Then get its url
  //Fetch the web page and store it in the cell next to edited url
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Frederic. I got another problem. Then i am trying to run this script, Editor shows me: ReferenceError: Subject "Spreadsheet" not defined. Any ideas?

Comment: it goes forward, but stuck in string 13: Attribute is specified with no value: url (string · 13). Debug shows me that data of web page was taken. But the program can not display them in column B. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm sorry, Spreadsheet should be SpreadsheetApp. I will try to debug it later today. I thought it would work.

Comment: I updated it to skip blank cells and get the B column range to be the right size. It worked with 2 urls when I tried it.